# How to set a default path to my new Python 3.5 install?

Tags: python, python-3.5

I just installed python 3.5 from the official python website. It installed on my computer and it install on my computer under:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5
```

However, I am trying to run virtualenv and it will take me to this error message when I try to create a new virtual environment.

```
-bash: /Users/me/anaconda/bin/virtualenv: No such file or directory
```

I removed Anaconda from my computer but still unable to create a virtual environment under my python 3.5 path even though it has installed.

Here is my bash_profile.

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3.4
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# Setting PATH for Python 2.7
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

### Added by the Heroku Toolbelt
export PATH="/usr/local/heroku/bin:$PATH"

# Setting PATH for Python 3.4
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# Setting PATH for Python 3.4
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# Setting PATH for Python 3.4
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

##
# Your previous /Users/lewismenelaws/.bash_profile file was backed up as /Users/lewismenelaws/.bash_profile.macports-saved_2015-02-25_at_15:58:24
##

# MacPorts Installer addition on 2015-02-25_at_15:58:24: adding an appropriate PATH variable for use with MacPorts.
```

Comment: When you create a `virtual environment` it is still looking where anaconda had it.  Could you post the output of your `.bash_profile`? Also, what does `which virtualenv` give you in terminal?

Comment: Personally, I don't believe 3.5 was ready for prime time when they released it, there were a number of bugs apparent on release.  I suggest sticking to 3.4.3 for the time being.  That said, try installing it with the 'add to path' option checked, and see what it adds to your path variable.  That would let you know if something wonky is going on.

Comment: @meter thanks for the reply. I am fairly new to the terminal. What command can I use to output this?

Comment: simply type `which virtualenv` and press enter

Comment: To get your bash profile put this in terminal and press enter `cd ~; nano .bash_profile`

Comment: Check the OP again @meter. I also get this when I run  `which virtualenv ` i get this


 `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/virtualenv `


which is the correct one I am looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding

```
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

I don't see any path for python 3.5, however.

Honestly I would scratch all this and install python, pip and virtualenv using homebrew so everything is in `/usr/local/bin/`

Comment: Gave that a try and I couldn't get virtualenv to work. However, I did add the path and whenever i run which python3 I do get the path I was intentionally trying to get.